# Restlet and consuming/storing files

Tags: java, post, put, server-sent-events, restlet-2.0

How would one handle consuming an attachment from a client POST/PUT request on the server side and store that file in a local folder, all using Restlet ?

My thoughts are as follows:

Setup Server as follows:

```
new MailServerComponenet.start();

public MailServer(){
    getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8111);
    getDefaultHost().attachDefault(new MailServer());
    server.getContext().getParameters().set("tracing", "true");
}

@Put
public void store(Form form){
    // *And here is where I am not sure*
}
```

Thanks for any insight and help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the following steps you should follow to implement your Restlet application:

- Create a component

  ```
  Component component = new Component();
  ```
- Create an application and attach it on the component

  ```
  component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8182);

  Application application = new MyApplication();
  component.getDefaultHost().attachDefault(application);

  component.start();
  ```
- Configure the application within the method `createInboundRoot` (create a router and attach server resource on it)

  ```
  public class MyApplication extends Application {
      @Override
      public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
          Router router = new Router();
          router.attach("/test", MyServerResource.class);
          return router;
      }
  }
  ```
- Implement the server resources

  ```
  public class MyServerResource extends ServerResource {
      @Post
      public Representation handlePost(Representation repr) {
          (...)
      }
  }
  ```

Now the global frame is implemented, I would wonder how you would send the content to Restlet. Is it simple binary content within the request payload or multi-part content?

- Binary content

  ```
  @Post
  public Representation handlePost(FileRepresentation fileRepr) {
      fileRepr.write(new FileOutputStream(
                 new File("/tmp/myfile.txt"))); 
      return null;
  }
  ```
- Multipart content. You can have a look at this answer in this case: [File Upload with Description in Restlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292523/file-upload-with-description-in-restlet/28294825#28294825)

Hope it helps you,
Thierry