# Restlet multpart form file upload fails with UnknownSizeException

Tags: rest, file-upload, client, multipartform-data, restlet

I'm try to simulate form submission with attached file and some parameters using restlet client. from the browser submissions the server is working fine but the problem is when trying to upload using the  restlet it fails.

The upload code is. I removed validation and exception handling for readability.

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(targetUrl);
cr.setCookies(cookie);
FormDataSet form = new FormDataSet();
form.getEntries().add(new FormData("title", request.getTitle()));

File f = new File(request.getFilePath());
FileRepresentation file = new FileRepresentation(f,MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
FormData fd = new FormData("upload_file", file); 
form.getEntries().add(fd);
form.setMultipart(true);

Representation responseObject = cr.post(form);
```

But the server complains that the content size is missing from the request.

> org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$UnknownSizeException: the request was rejected because its size is unknown

What am I doing wrong in the above code.
FYI the server is also written using restlet and follows the code sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292523/file-upload-with-description-in-restlet).

I found a restlet blog which has some alternative method [here](http://restlet.com/blog/2015/10/27/implementing-file-upload-with-restlet-framework/). But They refer to a class "MultipartRepresentation" which I was not able to locate in restlet distribution. In here I might have missing a extension jar file but still I cannot locate such.

Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 0):

I made a test using your code with Restlet 2.3.1 and I can't reproduce your problem.

Here is the content of the request it produced:

```
POST /upload HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: Jetty/9.2.6.v20141205
Date: Thu, 05 Nov 2015 15:48:31 GMT
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---Aa1Bb2Cc3---
Accept: */*
Host: localhost:8182
User-Agent: Restlet-Framework/2.3.1
Content-Length: 248

-----Aa1Bb2Cc3---
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"

request.getTitle()
-----Aa1Bb2Cc3---
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload_file"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: multipart/form-data

some text
-----Aa1Bb2Cc3-----
```

Here are the dependencies I have in my test project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
    <version>${restlet-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.jetty</artifactId>
    <version>${restlet-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>${restlet-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.html</artifactId>
    <version>${restlet-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Could you give more details about the exact dependencies you used and the content of the sent request?

I guess that it could be linked to the client extension you use (the default one?). In my case, I used the one from the Jetty extension...

Thanks!
Thierry